# Adding CR or LF in HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, title, carriage-return

To explain this shortly, I have an mouseenter Jquery event firing up an AJAX call. And a Jquery UI tooltip.

```
$(function()
{
    $(document).tooltip({track:true});
    $('#NewUser').mouseenter(function(){AJAXValidation("NewUser")});
});
```

Here is the call:

```
function AJAXValidation(section)
{
    var request = $.ajax(
    {
        url: "ProcessJRT.php",
        type: "POST",
        contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        data:
        {
            validate:section
        }
    });

    request.done(
        function(message)
        {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            $(div).html(message);
            $(div).children().each
            (
                function(i)
                {
                    var title = '';

                    if($('#' + $(this).attr('id')).attr('title') != null)
                    {
                        title = $('#' + $(this).id).attr('title');
                    }

                    title += $(this).html() + '\r\n';

                    $('#' + $(this).id).attr('title', title);
                }
            );
        });
}
```

What it does now is it take the `<div>`s from `message` and it place them in a parent `<div>`. (In my code the div already exist, I changed that part so the question would stay as short as possible).

I then take the text from those `<div>` and I want to place them in the corresponding `<input/>` title attribute.

Everything work just perfect here exepte this stupid little thing:

I am unable to add a LN or a CR in the title so all the texts from the divs would be on separate line...

I have tried adding a `</br>` inside the attribute like this:

```
function(i)
{
    var title = '';

    if($('#' + $(this).id).attr('title') != null)
    {
        title = $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).attr('title');
    }

    title += $(this).html() + '</br>';//<---See I added a BR here 

    $('#' + $(this).id).attr('title', title);
}
```

But it display the `</br>` as normal text. I than tried `String.fromCharCode(13)` but did'nt work, I tried jus `'\n'` or `'\r\n'` and still does work.

Can someone point out were I am derping on this one??

Thanks!

EDIT:

Changed the `$('#' + $(this).attr('id'))` to `$('#' + $(this).id)`.

Comment: It's invalid to have HTML in attributes if it is not properly escaped. Thus, I suspect that jQuery is escaping the HTML when adding `title` to the `title` attribute.

Comment: Just a note, if it should be anything, it should not be `</br>` but `<br>`, alternativly `<br />`. Sure most browsers will evaluate it as `<br>` anyway, but it is an malformed tag.

Comment: If your intent is to put line breaks into the generated jQuery tooltip, then you should look at implementing your own [**`content`**](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content) function, and decoding the html entities there. '\r\n' does not render as new lines in HTML documents, so you will need to use `<br>`. It just has to be escaped while it lives in the `title` attribute, and unescaped when you render the HTML tooltip replacement.

Comment: Now that you point it out @Matt Ball it does seems complicated but the $('#'+ ....) represent a dom element and the $(this) is the element in my loop.

Comment: @crush actually, I think the OP isn't wrong here - the `.each()` loop isn't iterating over elements in the DOM. However, it should still be simplified by caching the selected element, and using `$('#' + this.id)`.

Comment: I see, he is essentially working with two separate documents.

Comment: @Sebastien Your options are to override the `content` function of jqueryui's tooltip, or use a plugin like is suggested in the answers below that would basically do that for you.

Comment: @crush Thanks! your comment gave me an idea of what to do and i resolve the thing!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I resolve my problem with the idea that @crush gave me:

First:

I removed the tooltip initialization from the function that fire the event :

```
$(function()
{
    $('#NewUser').mouseenter(function(){AJAXValidation("NewUser")});
});
```

Next:

I changed the "done" function so I would initialise a new tooltip each time with html content (FYI JQuery tooltip can format HTML)

Here what it look like now:

```
function(message)
{
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    $(div).html(message);

    var title = '';

    $(div).children().each
    (
        function(i)
        {
            if($('#' + $(this).id).attr('title') != null)
            {
                title = $('#' + $(this).id).attr('title');
            }

            title += $(this).html() + '</br>';

            $(document).tooltip({content:title, items:('#' + $(this).id)});
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't format the title attribute in that way, it doesn't work, and will be different across different browsers.

Try the jquery plugin qTip to achieve what you want. (looks good too!)
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Alternatively, you can cheat by using `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` etc, to push the text to the next line. but this is flaky at best.